# SQL Script - Check if a IP has been black listed

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I am studying SQL, and I would like your advice, to see if this code is written properly, or better way to do it.
This script create:

- a table to store IPs address that are Black Listed
- a sproc to allow spitting an IP address in 4 octet
- a SPROC that allow to check if a IP is Black Listed or not
  Please let me know! thanks!

  ```
  -- Black Listed Table
  CREATE TABLE UtlBlacklistedIPs 
          ( 
              octet1 TINYINT, 
              octet2 TINYINT, 
              octet3 TINYINT, 
              octet4 TINYINT 
          );
  ```

1 SPROC

```
    -- Convert an IP address in 4 octet for db storing
  CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.storeIPoctetsv1 
   @ip CHAR(15) 
  AS 
  BEGIN 
   SET NOCOUNT ON 
   INSERT UtlBlacklistedIPs(octet1, octet2, octet3, octet4) 
    SELECT 
     CONVERT(TINYINT, PARSENAME(@ip, 4)), 
     CONVERT(TINYINT, PARSENAME(@ip, 3)), 
     CONVERT(TINYINT, PARSENAME(@ip, 2)), 
     CONVERT(TINYINT, PARSENAME(@ip, 1)) 
  END
```

2 SPROC

```
-- SPROC check if an IP address has been black listed
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sprocCheckIp
     @ip CHAR(15)
    AS
    BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON
     DECLARE
     @octet1 tinyint,
     @octet2 tinyint,
     @octet3 tinyint,
     @octet4 tinyint;

     SET @octet1 = CONVERT(tinyint, PARSENAME(@ip, 4)); 
     SET @octet2 = CONVERT(tinyint, PARSENAME(@ip, 3));
     SET @octet3 = CONVERT(tinyint, PARSENAME(@ip, 2));
     SET @octet4 = CONVERT(tinyint, PARSENAME(@ip, 1));

     IF EXISTS ( 
      SELECT octet1, octet2, octet3, octet4
      FROM UtlBlacklistedIPs
      WHERE
      octet1 =@octet1
      AND octet2 =@octet2
      AND octet3 =@octet3
      AND octet4 =@octet4
      )
       BEGIN
        PRINT 'Ip: '+@ip+' is black listed'
       END

      ELSE
       BEGIN     
        PRINT 'Ip: '+@ip+' is NOT black listed'
       END     
    END
```

Some values

```
    -- Insert dummy values
DECLARE @i INT 
SET @i = 0 
WHILE @i < 2000 
BEGIN 

    EXEC dbo.storeIPoctetsv1 @ip = '204.71.34.21' 
    EXEC dbo.storeIPoctetsv1 @ip = '12.38.145.32' 
    EXEC dbo.storeIPoctetsv1 @ip = '127.0.0.1' 

    SET @i = @i + 1 
END
```

Use the SPROC

```
    -- Use SPROc
    EXEC dbo.sprocCheckIp '125.254.125.111' -- NOT black listed Ip
    EXEC dbo.sprocCheckIp '204.71.34.21' -- black listed Ip
```

Comment: +1 For interesting use of `PARSENAME`

Comment: Store an ipv4 address as an int (because that's what it is). The 4-part dotted representation is just a representation.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're going to use this outside of the database, presumably in .NET? In that case, I'd re-structure like this:

- SProc to store black-listed IP, with four octets as input
- SProc to check any IP, with four octets as input and 0 or 1 as output (using `RETURN`, not `PRINT`)
- Do the splitting of IP addresses in .NET instead. SQL Server has very poor string handling, so you're far better off writing a class `Ip` with a static method `int[] ToOctets(string ip)` that handles this for you. You'll use it as such: `var octs = Ip.ToOctets("213.82.158.93")`
- When you check if an IP is black-listed or not, you call ExecuteScalar (or whatever the method to get a scalar value from a stored procedure might be called with the connector you prefer) to get the result.

Comment: Thanks Tomas, I appreciate your advices!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Thomas, but do have a question: why are you storing the IP in 4 separate columns? If the whole point of the exercise is to track "black-listed IP addresses", then when would you ever need to examine just a piece of the IP address -- wouldn't you always be looking at the entire thing? So splitting/re-combining octets seems unnecessary. It causes you to write a lot of extra T-SQL too.

Comment: using 4 octet stored as tinyint you save space in db, instead id you use a unique char(15) for storing ips you will end with a 15 bytes data type

Comment: I found the test (that I think you were using as your reference) done about 10 years ago, comparing tiny int, int & char (http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-should-i-store-an-ip-address-in-sql-server.html)  I wonder though -- that being a 2000 db, if it would be worth running again with a more modern database (SQL-2005 or 2008, etc.) using varchar instead of char, smallint instead of int, or other improvements that have become available since 2000.